# How do I add a google doc to the Docs template gallery?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-template

I have a template document in Google Docs. It was added to the template gallery of my work account a few years back.

When I am logged in to my personal account (not my work account) it shows as added to the template gallery, but when I look in the gallery, it is not there.

I can't work out how to add it. I went to the Google Docs home page as directed by one website, but could not find a way to add the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Google is no longer allowing people using consumer accounts, like those having a primary email address from gmail.com,  to submit templates. This is only possible now with accounts from Google Workspace-supported editions if the corresponding organization has enabled this feature.

Reference

- [How to submit a template](https://knowledge.workspace.google.com/kb/how-to-sumbit-a-template-000007386)